# Foreach loop in the middle of an array. Or something similar

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to loop through the rows as shown below but am obviously getting an error with this code. I have just added the foreach loop here to show where I need it to loop through. 
Hope that makes sense...

```
$data = array(
    'cols' => array(
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Score', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Result', 'type' => 'number')
    ),

    'rows' => array(

        //need this query to loop through the rows
        $the_query3 = new WP_Query( 'post_type'   => 'handicap' );
        foreach($the_query3->posts as $post) {

            array('c' => array(array('v' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hcap_date', true)), array('v' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hcap_score', true)), array('v' => $result))),
        };// end foreach loop
    )          
);

$chart->load(json_encode($data));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the element with an empty array:

```
$data = array(
    'cols' => array(
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Score', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Result', 'type' => 'number')
    ),
    'rows' => array()          
);
```

Then use a loop to fill it in:

```
foreach($the_query3->posts as $post) {
    $data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(array('v' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hcap_date', true)), array('v' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hcap_score', true)), array('v' => $result)));
}
```